# NSString to NSURL conversion removing some part of path

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I have attached the image of both my url and path logged in console. When I convert my String to URL why some part of it is removed.

"..." are added in the url in place of some path.

Can anyone suggest any method which would give me the exact same string in URL.

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smiley" ofType:@"gif"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path];
```

[image]

Comment: can you try logging your url using NSLog like `NSLog(@"url is: %@ ", [url absoluteString]);`

Comment: NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

Comment: @iYoung [url absoluteString] works, but it is a string, when i pass this, it gives me warning. I need to use it as url.

Comment: @Birendra - when i use "fileURLWithPath:" it adds "file://" before the path, same happens with "initWithString".

Comment: you have to remove "file://" from url? if yes then why?

Answer (score 2):

URLs start always with a scheme (`http://`, `ftp://`, `file://` etc), to create an URL from a file system path starting with a single slash you have to use the API `fileURLWithPath` which adds the `file://` scheme.

However the simplest solution is to use the URL related API of `NSBundle`:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"smiley" withExtension:@"gif"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smiley" ofType:@"gif"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```